# Lotus Notes display documents have V2-Style Attachment in View

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

My Lotus Notes Client is R6.5

**I have V2-Style Attachment problem**

I would like to show those documents which contains V2-Style Attachment in View.

But I have no idea about how to write this View Selection Fomula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done. You would need to compare @Attachments with the number of attachment references within rich text fields in the document, but there's no way to get that in formula language.

An alternative would be to use a folder instead of a view, and write a LotusScript or Java agent to compare the NotesRichTextItem.EmbeddedObjects array with what you get from Evaluate("@Attachments").  If you find any attachments that aren't referenced in the rich text, you would use NotesDocument.PutInFolder.